# using and multiple else if statement- output unexpected end of file

Tags: php

i have  been trying to echo the codes and it not working properly. after reading up ifelse statement, i still cant figure what wrong with  this statement in php outputting unexpected end of file.

```
       <?php if($current_type){?>
       <?php echo " Manage Product Type ";      
       echo "Menu Name:".  $current_type["product_type"]."<br>";?>  
       <a href= "edit_category.php">Edit Subject</a>;
       <?php}elseif($current_category){?>
        <h1> Manage Product category </h1>
       <?php echo "Menu Name:".  $current_category["category_name"];?>
      <?php}elseif ($current_product){?>
        <h1> Manage Products </h1>
      <?php echo "Menu Name:".  $current_product["product_names"];?>
      <?php }else{?>
        Please select a Product, category, or type
       <?php};?>
```

Comment: there should not be semicolon in your last line after the bracket.

Comment: did you run it without the semi-colon before you commented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a huge improvement on the readability of your code. It uses [PHP alternate syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

```
<?php if($current_type): ?>
  <h1>Manage Product Type</h1>
  Menu Name: <?php echo $current_type["product_type"] ?><br>
  <a href="edit_category.php">Edit Subject</a>
<?php elseif ($current_category): ?>
  <h1>Manage Product category</h1>
  Menu Name: <?php echo $current_category["category_name"] ?>
<?php elseif ($current_product): ?>
  <h1>Manage Products</h1>
  Menu Name <?php echo $current_product["product_names"] ?>
<?php else: ?>
  Please select a Product, category, or type
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
   <?php if($current_type){ ?>
   <?php echo " Manage Product Type ";      
   echo "Menu Name:".  $current_type["product_type"]."<br>";?>  
   <a href= "edit_category.php">Edit Subject</a>;
   <?php } else if($current_category){ ?>
    <h1> Manage Product category </h1>
   <?php echo "Menu Name:".  $current_category["category_name"];?>
  <?php } else if ($current_product){?>
    <h1> Manage Products </h1>
  <?php echo "Menu Name:".  $current_product["product_names"];?>
  <?php } else {?>
    Please select a Product, category, or type
   <?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this rationale

<?php if(1 == 1) { ?>
    <?php echo "xxxxx"; ?>
<?php } elseif(1 == 2) { ?>
    <?php echo "xxxxx"; ?>
<?php } elseif (1 == 3){ ?>
    <?php echo "xxxxx"?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <?php echo "xxxxx"?>
<?php } ?>
```